# how to send multipart data and json data together in one request using curl or postman

Tags: spring, curl, postman, multipart

I have a case where I have to save json data and upload a file in one request.

this is how I am doing in spring

```
      public void profile (@RequestBody @Validated @Valid ProfileDTO profileDTO,
         @RequestPart("file") @Valid MultipartFile file){
/// saving to db    
}
```

Now how can I test this using curl and postman?

Comment: How about adding `MultipartFile` inside the DTO? Then you can do it directly

Comment: Actually MultipartFile is part of another DTO. So can not send it inside this DTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1104

You can not do this in Postman yet (postman devs works on this feature).

Other users send json data as a file, but it is only a work around available in Postman.